# FLOT: Order the y axis by minimum date

Tags: jquery, charts, flot, gantt-chart

The ticks I am passing is the following:

```
ticks:
    0: [3, Tender Period, 2014-03-11]
    1: [1, Pre-Contract Preparation, 2014-03-17]
    2: [2, Contract Period, 2014-06-10]
```

[image: Graph]

But in my chart, its started with [3, Tender Period] then why my second object is `[2 Contact Period]` Period rather than `[1 Pre-Contract Preparation]`?

I don't have any idea why it is changed when it comes to the chart!

Comment: Please post relevant code. What are you sending to Flot?

Comment: Hello Mark, I just added the data what i am sending. Thanks @markthomas

Comment: I suggest that you tag this question with JavaScript and/or JQuery, since your question is not really about Ruby.

Comment: I added the jquery tag instead of ruby. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's not the order but the number (first argument i.e. [3,1,2]) of the tick that gives the order. You need to renumber so you get a higher number for the earlier bar.